# How to paste or import CSV containing newlines into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to copy/paste or export a large number of lines from another application to Google Sheets.  However, I discovered that when I copy/paste, any newlines are silently removed.  When I try to export as CSV (field separator=**,** Encloser=**"** Line terminator=\r\n) and import the CSV, the newlines are completely breaking the row and spilling into the next row.

What separator, encloser, and terminator do I need to export the CSV as for Google Sheets to properly put the newlines in the cells themselves?

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/67626/88163

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded a CSV from Google Sheets which contained newlines in a cell and I see the Google separates each line in the CSV by '\r\n' but each individual newline in a cell is only '\n'.  In addition, lines containing '\n' need to be quoted.  So the answer is:

- separator: **,**
- encloser: **"**
- line terminator: **\r\n**
- but also, any new lines in a cell must be '\n' (not '\r', '\r\n' or '\n\r')